# Include header files without ".h" format

Tags: c++, include, header-files, file-extension

I know that to include headers you must type `#include <header.h>`.

Is there a way to include the header as `#include <header>`, like we do with `iostream` or `cstdlib`?

Comment: name the file `header`.

Comment: When doing `#include <$(something>`, $(something) is the name of the file, so just dont give it the .h extension

Comment: @tkausl That can get confusing on Windows :-D ...

Comment: _I  know that to include headers you must type #include <header.h>_ that is wrong.

Comment: @tkausl told you how, but why do you want to? The header files without the .h or .hh or .hpp extension are typically for built-in library includes.  It would be confusing to roll your own like that.

Comment: But not only built-in functions do that. Qt libraries are accessed like that, for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just rename `header.h` to `header`. The files `iostream`, `cstdlib`, etc are files with exactly those names that don't have any extension. For example, here is a screenshot of Visual Studio's `iostream` file in Windows Explorer:

[image]

Usually when you create your own header file it has the extension `.h` (or sometimes `.hpp`), but nothing in the C++ standard forces them to have any specific extension. You can include a file with any you want as long as its contents is valid C++. Some libraries like the C++ standard library or Qt don't have any extension on their header files just to make your code look nice. Most IDEs automatically add a `.h` extension when you create a header file because `.h` is the extension that header files usually have, but that's just a convention, you can give them any extension you want.